# I'm trying to write a code that uses method overload to print out my statement

Tags: java

I have this program that has to ask the user if they want to enter the students name only or to enter the students name and banner ID. Then they can type either "just name" or "both", then the appropriate question will follow. Using the `Student` class I made, I have to use the appropriate constructor to print out the answer to the screen, either just students name or students name and banner ID. I think I'm getting messed up on how to create the constructors, the instructions say to create three constructors, one that takes the name and banner ID, one that takes just name, and one that takes no arguments and it wants me to create them inside the `Student` class, I thought they got created inside the `main` class to access the `Student` class.

```
package classwork6_2;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClassWork6_2 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Would you like to enter student's name only or name and banner ID?: ");
    String response = s.nextLine();
    String name;
    long banID;
    if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("just name")){
        System.out.print("Enter student's name: ");
        name = s.nextLine();
    } else if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("both")){

        System.out.print("Enter students name: ");
        name = s.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter student's banner ID: ");
        banID = s.nextLong();


    }

    Student nameBanID = new Student();
    nameBanID.setNameBanID(name, banID);
    Student n = new Student(); 
    n.setName(name);

    System.out.print("Students name is: " + n.getName());
    System.out.print("Student's banner ID is: " + n.getNameBanID()); 
  }   
}
```

**Student class**

```
package classwork6_2;

public class Student {


  private String name;
  private String bannerID;


  Student nameBanID = new Student();
  Student n = new Student();
  Student none = new Student();

  public String getNameBanID(){

    return bannerID + name;
  }

  public String getName(){

    return name;
  }

  public void setNameBanID(String name, long banID){

    bannerID = bannerID + name;
  }

  public void setName(String name){

    this.name = name;
  }    
}
```

Comment: I don't see a question here.  What is the specific problem?

Comment: When I try to compile my code it gives me an error on line 11 of my Student class program. I'm wondering if someone can explain how to properly use the constructors to get my code to compile correctly

Comment: @MattL. I am getting no compile errors (in Student class where you say your issue is)

Comment: change `String name;` to `String name = "";` It looks like you aren't initializing the String. Do the same for `long banID`.

Comment: You need to init `banID` in `main` method in `ClassWork6_2` before call to `nameBanID.setNameBanID(name, banID);`

Comment: When I go to compile this in my 'main' class, it crashes right after I enter the student's name, saying that the problem is stemming from line 11 in my 'Student' class.

Comment: I initialized it now, I made `String name = null;` and I made `long banID = 0;` and it still crashes right after I enter the students name.

Comment: Could you please add exception stack trace to the question then?

Comment: @Ivan it's stack overflow.

Comment: @MattL. you need to comment out/remove initialization of `Student` variables from your `Student` class because it causes endless recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a stack overflow error because of these lines in your Student class

```
Student nameBanID = new Student();
Student n = new Student();
Student none = new Student();
```

In your ClassWork6_2 when you call `Student nameBanID = new Student();` you are creating an instance of the Student class and assigning it to the `nameBanID` variable. When you are creating an instance of the class it is immediately hitting the line that says `Student nameBanID = new Student();` causing your code to go through a loop of creating a new student until a stack overflow error occurs.

Here are how the three constructors should look

```
private String name;
//changed bannerID to long to match input from code example
private long bannerID;

public Student(String name){
    setName(name);
}
public Student(long bannerID){
    setBannerID(bannerID);
}
public Student(String name, long bannerID){
    setName(name);
    setBannerID(bannerID);
}
```

Your current code does not define any constructors, but java will create a default constructor for you when you do not define one. Once your constructor is defined you can create a student object using those constructors.

```
String studentName = "Jeffery";
long bannerID = 123456789;
Student studentWithName = new Student(studentName);
Student studentWithBannerID = new Student(bannerID);
Student studentWithNameAndBannerID = new Student(studentName,bannerID);
```

Here are all of the modifications I made to your student class

```
class Student {
    private String name;
    private long bannerID;
    public Student(String name){
        setName(name);
    }
    public Student(long bannerID){
        setBannerID(bannerID);
    }
    public Student(String name, long bannerID){
        setName(name);
        setBannerID(bannerID);
    }
    public Student(){}
    public String getNameBanID(){

        return bannerID + name;
    }
    public String getName(){

        return name;
    }
    public long getBannerID(){
        return bannerID;
    }
    public void setBannerID(long bannerID){

        this.bannerID = bannerID;
    }
    public void setName(String name){

        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new `Student` object, you then create and initialize another 3 Student objects. This causes a recursion of Student creation, resulting in a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

You also don't seem to have a constructor for your `Student` class (eg. `public Student () {...}`). Ideally, the constructor is where you would initialize your class variables.

Try this: instead of creating the 3 `Student` objects in the class itself, create them in the `main` method. Also add in a constructor method for your `Student` class